# Ember data dynamic model not loaded in the store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a `search` model in my app which loads dynamically when the users types something in the search box. The `this.store.query('search', {query: "xyz"})` is called on `keyUp()` and fetches the data from the API backend. However, looks like I'm missing something here because in Ember Inspector I don't see the data to be loaded for the `search` model. Anyway, this is not my biggest concern because I don't know if ember inspector loads data from the store dynamically or only on refresh. My problem is that I can't access the data returned from the server in the template.

I have to mention that I don't have a route for search results, this is more like IMDb-like search box, where the results are loaded as search box kind of autocomplete instant results.

My code:

**/templates/components/search-box.hbs**

```hbs
{{input value=query}}
<div>
  // search results should be displayed here
</div>
```

**/templates/components/app-bar.hbs**

```
<nav>
    {{#link-to 'index' tagName='button'}}Home{{/link-to}}

    {{search-box value=query action="search"}}
</nav>
```

**/templates/application.hbs**

```hbs
{{app-bar action="search"}}
{{outlet}}
```

**/components/search-box.js**

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({

    keyUp: function(e){
        if (this.get('value'))
            this.sendAction('action', this.get('value'));
    }

});
```

**/components/app-bar.js**

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    actions: {
        search: function(query){
            this.sendAction('action', query);
        }
    }
});
```

**/controllers/application.js**

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    actions: {
        search: function(query){
            this.store.query('search', {text: query});
        }
    }
});
```

Shouldn't `this.store.query('search', {text: query});` automatically push records into the store? If it does, how can I access them inside my `/templates/components/search-box.hbs` component?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The model hook in the route would usually set up your model, but if your loading records from the controller you need to do this yourself.

```
this.set('model', this.store.peekAll('search'));
```

Comment: how to acces the model inside the component then?

Comment: You will need to pass the model up through the components to access it in templates
{{app-bar action="search" model=model}}
{{search-box value=query action="search" model=model}}

In template you can now iterate over the model
{{#each model as |result|}}
  {{result.name}}
{{/each}}